# How do I write "Discord" (the app) in katakana?

Tags: words, katakana

Quick question: How do I write "Discord" (the app) in katakana?

Comment: These kinds of questions without any evidence of prior research will typically be closed, but it's usually quite easy to find the names of major products. Just check Wikipedia https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discord_(%E3%82%BD%E3%83%95%E3%83%88%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A7%E3%82%A2)

Comment: For anyone who is too lazy to search: Discord ==> `ディスコード`

Comment: I  searched but I didn't find anything. I only found translations for the verb "to discord"

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tip for any time you want to write something in Katakana.
Go to the English wikipedia article, then click the Japanese version.
This is a perfect way to find the proper spelling for certain brands or city names in the Katakana script!
Cheers!